# Problem when customizing ToC with abntex2 and etoc

Tags: biblatex, luatex, etoc, abntex2

I need to customize the ToC of the text as follows:
[image: Desired ToC appearence]

But when using the MWE bellow:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
oneside,
a4paper,
hyphens,
chapter=TITLE,                          % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
section=TITLE,                          % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%subsection=TITLE,                      % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
%subsubsection=TITLE,                   % títulos de subsubseções em letras maiúsculas
%subsubsubsection=TITLE,
%sumario=abnt-6027-2012,
%sumario=tradicional,
english,
brazil,
]{abntex2} % 
%

\hypersetup{hidelinks}


\setlength\bibitemsep{3\itemsep}

%Configurando Fontes
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfontsize}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsectionfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsubsectionfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\itshape}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsubsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\setlength\afterchapskip{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{etoc}

\makeatletter

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{\baselineskip} % Espaçamento entre capítulos
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2em}

\let\old@chapter\l@chapter
\let\old@chapternumberline\chapternumberline
\etocsetstyle{chapter}{}{}{\old@chapter{\old@chapternumberline{\etocnumber}\etoclink{\normalsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase\etocthename}}{\etocpage}}{}%


\let\old@section\l@section
\etocsetstyle{section}{}{}
{\old@section{\normalfont\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}%


\let\old@subsection\l@subsection
\etocsetstyle{subsection}{}{}
{\old@subsection{\normalfont\bfseries\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}%


\let\old@subsubsection\l@subsubsection
\etocsetstyle{subsubsection}{}{}
{\old@subsubsection{\normalfont\bfseries\itshape\numberline{\etocnumber}{\etocname}}{\etocpage}}{}%

\makeatother


\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @ARTICLE{example,
        author  = {Other, Anthony Norman},
        title   = {Some things I did},
        year    = {2014},
        journal = {J.~Irrep. Res.},
        volume  = {1},
        number  = {1},
        pages   = {1-10}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
style = abnt,                       % Sistema alfabético
backend = biber,                    % Força usar Biber
%style = abnt-numeric,              % Sistema numérico
%style = abnt-ibid,                 % Notas de referência
giveninits,
repeatfields,
justify,
%indent,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents*
    \chapter{Introdução}
    \lipsum[3-5]\cite{example}.
        \section{INTRO I}
        \lipsum[3-6]\cite{example}.
        \subsection{Intro II}
        \lipsum[7-9]\cite{example}.
        \subsubsection{Intro III}
        \lipsum[9-10]\cite{example}.

    \chapter{Revisão}   
    \lipsum[12-14]\cite{example}.
        \section{REVISÃO I}
        \lipsum[11-14]\cite{example}.
        \subsection{Revisão II}
        \lipsum[14-16]\cite{example}.
        \subsubsection{Revisão III}
        \lipsum[17-18]\cite{example}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However, what I get is:

[image: what I get]

The "REFERÊNCIAS" text, should be aligned with the rest, but there is a whitespace that is not included anywhere before it.

If I inspect the "MWE.toc" aux file, I find the following line:

**\setlength {\cftchapterindent }{\cftlastnumwidth } \setlength {\cftchapternumwidth }{2em}**

Which I suspect it's the culprit, but can't find where (already inspect all class files to no avail) it is included on the ".toc" file. If i compile it using LuaLaTeX (need it for a fontspec on the original file).

Now what is bugging me even more, if I toggle **%sumario=abnt-6027-2012** and **%sumario=tradicional**, randomly, and don't delete the ".toc" file, sometimes it is printed as intended, but it's nearly random, with more occurrences when doing the first then the later.

Comment: And since I got mail saying that: the line "\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2em}" on the MWE, can even be deleted, but it wont change the behavior of the last toc entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `abntex2` class appears to define a magic command `\tocprintchapter` that needs to be issued when you try to add a chapter ToC entry. That means we need to redefine the bibliography heading (from `abnt.bbx`) a bit

```
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \if@twoside
    \markboth{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}%
  \else
    \markright{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}%
  \fi
  \ifmemoirbibintoc
    {\phantomsection
     \tocprintchapter
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
    {}}
\makeatother
```

In total

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
oneside,
a4paper,
hyphens,
chapter=TITLE,
section=TITLE,
english,
brazil,
]{abntex2} % 

\setlength\bibitemsep{3\itemsep}

%Configurando Fontes
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfontsize}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsectionfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsubsectionfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\itshape}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXsubsubsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\setlength\afterchapskip{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{etoc}

\makeatletter

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{\baselineskip} % Espaçamento entre capítulos
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2em}

\let\old@chapter\l@chapter
\let\old@chapternumberline\chapternumberline
\etocsetstyle{chapter}{}{}{\old@chapter{\old@chapternumberline{\etocnumber}\etoclink{\normalsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase\etocthename}}{\etocpage}}{}%


\let\old@section\l@section
\etocsetstyle{section}{}{}
{\old@section{\normalfont\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}%


\let\old@subsection\l@subsection
\etocsetstyle{subsection}{}{}
{\old@subsection{\normalfont\bfseries\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}%


\let\old@subsubsection\l@subsubsection
\etocsetstyle{subsubsection}{}{}
{\old@subsubsection{\normalfont\bfseries\itshape\numberline{\etocnumber}{\etocname}}{\etocpage}}{}%

\makeatother


\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @ARTICLE{example,
        author  = {Other, Anthony Norman},
        title   = {Some things I did},
        year    = {2014},
        journal = {J.~Irrep. Res.},
        volume  = {1},
        number  = {1},
        pages   = {1-10}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
style = abnt,                       % Sistema alfabético
backend = biber,                    % Força usar Biber
%style = abnt-numeric,              % Sistema numérico
%style = abnt-ibid,                 % Notas de referência
giveninits,
repeatfields,
justify,
%indent,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \if@twoside
    \markboth{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}%
  \else
    \markright{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}%
  \fi
  \ifmemoirbibintoc
    {\phantomsection
     \tocprintchapter
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
    {}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents*
    \chapter{Introdução}
    \lipsum[3-5]\cite{example}.
        \section{INTRO I}
        \lipsum[3-6]\cite{example}.
        \subsection{Intro II}
        \lipsum[7-9]\cite{example}.
        \subsubsection{Intro III}
        \lipsum[9-10]\cite{example}.

    \chapter{Revisão}   
    \lipsum[12-14]\cite{example}.
        \section{REVISÃO I}
        \lipsum[11-14]\cite{example}.
        \subsection{Revisão II}
        \lipsum[14-16]\cite{example}.
        \subsubsection{Revisão III}
        \lipsum[17-18]\cite{example}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Nicely indented REFERÊNCIAS]